# MySQL 8.016 master with MariaDB 10.2 slave on AWS RDS, Character set '#255' is not a compiled character set

Tags: mysql, mariadb, amazon-rds, collation, master-slave-replication

I have a MySQL 8.016 master and a MariaDB 10.2 slave, both running on AWS RDS. This was working perfectly until today, when I figured I wanted to do chain replication instead, like this

MySQL 8.016 -> MySQL 8.016 -> MariaDB 10.2

However, after changing master on my MariaDB instance, I got the dreaded `Error 'Character set '#255' is not a compiled character set` error. I then tried changing back to the old master, but I still got this error! I had this problem when I first got my setup to work a few months back, and the first time, I solved it by purging the `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` collation from my MySQL instances, and as far as I can see, they are still purged.

Output from my MySQL 8.016 master instance

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                     |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-8.0.16.R1/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0,04 sec)

mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%collat%';                                                        +-------------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name                 | Value              |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection          | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database            | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server              | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| default_collation_for_utf8mb4 | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0,03 sec)
```

Output from my MariaDB 10.2 slave instance

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.0.0.186
                  Master_User: mariadb_slave
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin-changelog.022828
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 532651
               Relay_Log_File: relaylog.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 433
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin-changelog.022827
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: mysql.rds_sysinfo,innodb_memcache.cache_policies,mysql.rds_replication_status,mysql.plugin,mysql.rds_history,innodb_memcache.config_options
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 22
                   Last_Error: Error 'Character set '#255' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/rdsdbbin/mariadb-10.2.21.R1/share/charsets/Index.xml' file' on query. Default database: 'magnublo_scraping'. Query: 'BEGIN'
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 124
              Relay_Log_Space: 3150873
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 22
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Character set '#255' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/rdsdbbin/mariadb-10.2.21.R1/share/charsets/Index.xml' file' on query. Default database: 'magnublo_scraping'. Query: 'BEGIN'
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 36970531
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
                   Using_Gtid: No
                  Gtid_IO_Pos: 
      Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids: 
                Parallel_Mode: conservative
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: 
1 row in set (0,04 sec)
```

Is there some variable I could be missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be a serious problem when replicating between MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.x.

The default (for good technical reasons) `COLLATION` for the 8.0 is `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.  Note the "255" associated with it.  MariaDB has not yet adopted the Unicode 9.0 collations.

Furthermore, Oracle (MySQL 8.0) did a major rewrite of the collation code, thereby *possibly* making collation tables incompatible.

A *probable* fix is to switch to the next best general-purpose collation, `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` (246) (based on Unicode 5.20).  This would require `ALTERing` all the *columns'* collations.  `ALTER TABLE .. CONVERT TO ..` might be the fastest way.  Those could be generated via a `SELECT .. information_schema.tables ...`.

8.0.17:

```
mysql> show collation like 'utf8mb4%';
+----------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+---------------+
| Collation                  | Charset | Id  | Default | Compiled | Sortlen | Pad_attribute |
+----------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+---------------+
| utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci         | utf8mb4 | 255 | Yes     | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        | <-- Note
| utf8mb4_0900_as_ci         | utf8mb4 | 305 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_0900_as_cs         | utf8mb4 | 278 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_0900_bin           | utf8mb4 | 309 |         | Yes      |       1 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_bin                | utf8mb4 |  46 |         | Yes      |       1 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_croatian_ci        | utf8mb4 | 245 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_cs_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 266 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_cs_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 289 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_czech_ci           | utf8mb4 | 234 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_danish_ci          | utf8mb4 | 235 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_da_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 267 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_da_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 290 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_de_pb_0900_ai_ci   | utf8mb4 | 256 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_de_pb_0900_as_cs   | utf8mb4 | 279 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_eo_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 273 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_eo_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 296 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_esperanto_ci       | utf8mb4 | 241 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_estonian_ci        | utf8mb4 | 230 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_es_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 263 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_es_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 286 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_es_trad_0900_ai_ci | utf8mb4 | 270 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_es_trad_0900_as_cs | utf8mb4 | 293 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_et_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 262 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_et_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 285 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_general_ci         | utf8mb4 |  45 |         | Yes      |       1 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_german2_ci         | utf8mb4 | 244 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_hr_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 275 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_hr_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 298 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_hungarian_ci       | utf8mb4 | 242 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_hu_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 274 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_hu_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 297 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_icelandic_ci       | utf8mb4 | 225 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_is_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 257 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_is_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 280 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 303 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs_ks   | utf8mb4 | 304 |         | Yes      |      24 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_latvian_ci         | utf8mb4 | 226 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_la_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 271 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_la_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 294 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_lithuanian_ci      | utf8mb4 | 236 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_lt_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 268 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_lt_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 291 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_lv_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 258 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_lv_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 281 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_persian_ci         | utf8mb4 | 240 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_pl_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 261 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_pl_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 284 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_polish_ci          | utf8mb4 | 229 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_romanian_ci        | utf8mb4 | 227 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_roman_ci           | utf8mb4 | 239 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_ro_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 259 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_ro_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 282 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_ru_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 306 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_ru_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 307 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_sinhala_ci         | utf8mb4 | 243 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_sk_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 269 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_sk_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 292 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_slovak_ci          | utf8mb4 | 237 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_slovenian_ci       | utf8mb4 | 228 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_sl_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 260 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_sl_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 283 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_spanish2_ci        | utf8mb4 | 238 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_spanish_ci         | utf8mb4 | 231 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_sv_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 264 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_sv_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 287 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_swedish_ci         | utf8mb4 | 232 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_tr_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 265 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_tr_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 288 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_turkish_ci         | utf8mb4 | 233 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci     | utf8mb4 | 246 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     | <--
| utf8mb4_unicode_ci         | utf8mb4 | 224 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_vietnamese_ci      | utf8mb4 | 247 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
| utf8mb4_vi_0900_ai_ci      | utf8mb4 | 277 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_vi_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 300 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_zh_0900_as_cs      | utf8mb4 | 308 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
+----------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+---------------+
75 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

MariaDB 10.2.30:

```
mysql> SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8mb4%';
+------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+---------+
| Collation                    | Charset | Id   | Default | Compiled | Sortlen |
+------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+---------+
| utf8mb4_general_ci           | utf8mb4 |   45 | Yes     | Yes      |       1 |
| utf8mb4_bin                  | utf8mb4 |   46 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| utf8mb4_unicode_ci           | utf8mb4 |  224 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_icelandic_ci         | utf8mb4 |  225 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_latvian_ci           | utf8mb4 |  226 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_romanian_ci          | utf8mb4 |  227 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_slovenian_ci         | utf8mb4 |  228 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_polish_ci            | utf8mb4 |  229 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_estonian_ci          | utf8mb4 |  230 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_spanish_ci           | utf8mb4 |  231 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_swedish_ci           | utf8mb4 |  232 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_turkish_ci           | utf8mb4 |  233 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_czech_ci             | utf8mb4 |  234 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_danish_ci            | utf8mb4 |  235 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_lithuanian_ci        | utf8mb4 |  236 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_slovak_ci            | utf8mb4 |  237 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_spanish2_ci          | utf8mb4 |  238 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_roman_ci             | utf8mb4 |  239 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_persian_ci           | utf8mb4 |  240 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_esperanto_ci         | utf8mb4 |  241 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_hungarian_ci         | utf8mb4 |  242 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_sinhala_ci           | utf8mb4 |  243 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_german2_ci           | utf8mb4 |  244 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_croatian_mysql561_ci | utf8mb4 |  245 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci       | utf8mb4 |  246 |         | Yes      |       8 | <--
| utf8mb4_vietnamese_ci        | utf8mb4 |  247 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_croatian_ci          | utf8mb4 |  608 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_myanmar_ci           | utf8mb4 |  609 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_thai_520_w2          | utf8mb4 |  610 |         | Yes      |       4 |
| utf8mb4_general_nopad_ci     | utf8mb4 | 1069 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| utf8mb4_nopad_bin            | utf8mb4 | 1070 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| utf8mb4_unicode_nopad_ci     | utf8mb4 | 1248 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_unicode_520_nopad_ci | utf8mb4 | 1270 |         | Yes      |       8 |
+------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+---------+
33 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```